# Reload the page who open the Iframe

Tags: javascript

I build some widget that open a light box but with Iframe tag.

In the iframe there is a form that you have to fill out.

When you finish to fill all the fields I want to refresh the page who open the light box window...

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { window.opened.reload.href='index.php'; }
</script>
```

but it's not working...

there is something I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you're almost there - you can refer to the parent-window [using `window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent) instead of `window.opened` and the address is changed [using `[...].location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) instead of `[...].reload.href`. your code should look like

```
window.parent.location.href='index.php';
```

Comment: And if your iframes are nested, you can get all the way to the top of the tree by using `window.top`.